# Do I have to put get/set methods in the class definition in matlab ?

Tags: class, matlab, getter-setter

Is one forced to place all get and set functions in the class definition file in Matlab ?

I'm asking since this really makes the file a bit messy and defeats the purpose of having a class definition folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you use property set and get access methods (in fact any method with a dot in the name), you must include them within the `classdef` file, not in separate files. See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html#brgsek9-2).

However, if you have have a special reason to want to put as much as possible in separate files, you can define methods `getMyProp` and `setMyProp` in separate files, and then within the `classdef` file have the `get.myProp` and `set.myProp` functions call them.

Comment: I thought I'd seen it in the documentation but couldn't find the correct page, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you use them then you need to define them. but you can also define your variables as public.